# Forcefully deleting a file using c++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, file

I have a code in c++ running on linux server. In the code, I am using  function `unlink(filename)` to delete a file. Temporary files getting generated by the code itself are getting deleted successfully. But the files that I am putting manually, my code is unable to delete them. What could be the reason?

Comment: `my code is unable to delete them` - do you still see the file names when you list the directory contents? Or are you only observing that the disc space is still allocated and not reclaimed?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that function, but it is probably a problem of file permissions.

Comment: @Andreas : Yes. Those files are present even after the execution of code.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for the file ?

Comment: How are you running your C++ code? From the shell, or via a service?

Comment: @SamGamgee: I have checked the file permissions and it's same in both cases. I am just wondering if there is a way to forcefully delete the file.

Comment: [unlink](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) does delete "forcefully" - if file permissions allow it. Space is only reclaimed if there are no other directory entries referring to the same file - but the file name should be removed from the directory. You should really check the return code as @hyde suggests in the answer beloe.

Comment: Important thing about Unix file systems is also, that `unlink` merely deletes the directory entry. Even if that is the last entry pointing to the file, still if file is open in some process, file itself will not be deleted until other process actually closes it (this can generate nasty disk use leaks if a long-lived daemon process keeps opening but not closing large files).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
```

...

```
if (unlink(filename) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File '%s' unlink error (%d): %s\n", filename, errno, strerror(errno));
    // or just use perror("unlink") for less customizable error message
    // note: calling other functions before printing may change errno value
}
```

Resulting error message should reveal what the problem is.

Here's [errno man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno), and [unlink man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) will tell what errors it can return.

---

Hmm, since this is actually a C++ question, you could and possibly should replace `fprintf` with `std::cerr`, but in that case it *may* be necessary to first do `int errtmp = errno` and use that, to avoid iostream messing it up before it gets examined.

Also you could write `::unlink(filename)` if you want to be explicit that it is a symbol in the top level namespace, at least some people consider that good practice even when not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hyde for such a prompt and wonderful solution. I am an idiot who was just passing file name instead of complete path in case the file was put manually. Error message solved my problem. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @sajal No problem. Added some details about C++, since my solution was more like C code.

Comment: Instead of using fprintf, I redirected the output to a log file, so I was safe :)

Answer (score 1):

The way that for example `rm -f` works is that, if the file has protection that doesn't allow it to be deleted, it attempts to change the file protection and ownership, using the `chmod()` and `chown()` functions to "make it possible to delete the file". This is only really GUARANTEED to work if the user is `root` or the files actually belong to the user that runs the program.

Note that this becomes system dependent, you can't write code that changes file privileges etc in a way that works on both Windows and Unix-like OS's, and if you wanted to do this on, say, Symbian OS, it would be a third variant on how to do it Although there may be a "Posix compatible" `chmod()` available in some cases.

Comment: `rm -f` doesn't try to change permissions; it just suppresses some prompting and error reporting.  However, C++17 provides `std::filesystem` (based on Boost, natch) that lets you manipulate permissions if you want to.